# ng-model isn't being selected from an ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<select class="form-control"
        id="projects"
        ng-model="parent_id"
        ng-options="project.id as project.groupingName for project in projects">
</select>
```

There is a `project` that has a `gid` that matches the `parent_id`, but it still doesn't come as selected by default. To prove it, I did:

```
<div ng-repeat="project in projects" ng-show="project.gid === parent_id">
  {{ project }}
</div>
```

Comment: So you're using `ng-options` and a nested `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Sorry - I updated the code snippet

Comment: Please, clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: what about `parent_id` is that present on the `$scope`? I just made a Plunkr and it works: https://plnkr.co/edit/o4RJ2N?p=info

Comment: can you show some sample data that isn't working here?  this looks like perfectly functional code.

Comment: however, this looks like it could be a typo, since twice you mention the project has a `gid` but your ng-options has `project.id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see there's a gap in your code for parent_id and project id. I wrote some code for your requirement. If I understand correctly, you want to display the project if ID of that project equals parent_id. I've update ng-options for you correctly as they should track by "id" of the project.

Are you looking for something like http://codepen.io/aechannaveen/pen/NABbXq ?

```
    <html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <title>
        My Angular App
    </title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    </link>
</head>

<body class="container" ng-controller="InputCtrl">

     <select class="form-control" id="projects" ng-model="project" ng-options="project as project.groupingName for project in projects track by project.id">
      </select> 
  <div ng-show="project.id === parent_id">
    Project Selected :{{ project.groupingName }}
  </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('InputCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
$scope.parent_id = 2;
    $scope.projects = [
   {
        "groupingName": "ABC",
        "id": 1
    }, 
    {
        "groupingName": "CDE",
        "id": 2
    } ];



}]);
```